# arraylists and polymorphism

Tags: silverlight

I am working on a project and it contains a main, a parent class, and 3 subclasses. Right now I have it set up to when the program runs. I store each of the values for each subsclass in three seperate arrayliats. I need to make it so I use only one arraylist and polymorphism. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `List<ParentClass>` instead of your 3 array lists.

```
public class ParentClass {...}
public class ChildClass1 : ParentClass {...}
public class ChildClass2 : ParentClass {...}
public class ChildClass3 : ParentClass {...}

var list = new List<ParentClass>();
var child1 = new ChildClass1();
var child2 = new ChildClass2();
var child3 = new ChildClass3();
list.Add(child1);
list.Add(child2);
list.Add(child3);
```

When you'll read your children from the list, you can determine their type using either 'is' or 'as'.

```
if (list[0] is ChildClass1)
{
}

ChildClass1 child1 = list[0] as ChildClass1;
// child1 will be null if list[0] is not a ChildClass1
```